# One Signal REST API - Get the list of templates

Tags: rest, push-notification, onesignal

How are you?
In principle, sorry for my English.

I need to work with an integration with **One Signal REST API** both for web and mobile application, but I can't find any endpoint to bring the templates (and I need them to include the id of the template in the request body as indicated in the documentation of "`POST -> create notification`")

Does anyone know if there is an endpoint that brings me the list of templates?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that (as of the date, OneSignal REST API v8) it's not possible to obtain the OneSignal template_id via REST API

[image: Chat with OneSignal employee]

Answer (score 1):

- got to OneSignal console
- select the app
- select Messages > Templates
- select the template that you want to know its ID
- get the ID from the URL, like shown in the image below

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
But I need to get all templates by code (via REST API or something like that). Not by UI.

OneSignal (by chat) has already confirmed that it cannot be possible.